# Reloading UIView property with view in nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a few UIViews in my view controller xib file - 1, 2, 3.

View 1 is the view controller's main view.

Views 2 & 3 (which in the xib are outside the main View 1) are alse properties in the view controller. Because of this, I don't need to initialise them. I can just add them to my main view in code.

My question is: can i reload views 2 & 3. For instance, after I have change the labels and the view frames in view 2, can I reload the view to restore all the original layout etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainViewController" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *mainViewControllerSuperView = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *superViewsArray = [mainViewControllerSuperView subviews];
UIView *secondView = [superViewsArray objectAtIndex:1]; // index of view you need

self.mainViewController.secondView = secondView;
```

Or single line:

```
self.mainViewController.view = [[(UIView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainViewController" owner:self options:nil] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
```